# Using Uri connected IP camera to take pictures and record video with Windows UWP app

Tags: uwp, camera, ip, onvif, mediacapture

Connecting directly IP cameras is a new UWP feature. On this page: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/10/10/connecting-network-cameras-to-windows-10-devices/

It says:
"For streaming from a URI through the MediaCapture class, assign the desired URI to MediaCaptureInitializationSettings::DeviceUri. If credentials are required, they can be set through MediaCaptureInitializationSettings::DeviceUriPasswordCredential. The API supports ONVIF and generic RTSP server URIs. This allows applications to use the standard Windows Media APIs to capture video from generic cameras that do not conform to the ONVIF standards, or from an arbitrary URI without pairing."

**Update:**
Now I am able to connect to the camera successfully. The problem was with the format of the URI. I have Reolink-410 Camera

```
MediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
MediaCaptureInitializationSettings captureInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
captureInitSettings.DeviceUri = new 
   Uri("rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.241:554//h264Preview_01_main");
captureInitSettings.DeviceUriPasswordCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential
                {
                    UserName = "admin",
                    Password = "password"
                };
MediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;
MediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;

await MediaCapture.InitializeAsync(captureInitSettings);
```

After this I can take pictures successfully

```
....
await _app.VM.MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(GetImageEncodingProperties(), file);
```

But When I try to record video it throws exception:
{"The specified object or value does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36D5)"}

```
...
var _mediaRecording = await _app.VM.MediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateHevc(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto), file);// Exception here {"The specified object or value does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36D5)"}
//also tried with CreateMP4

await _mediaRecording.StartAsync();
```

I also have tried `await _mediaRecording.StartAsync();` which throws same exception.
{"The specified object or value does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36D5)"}

Comment: What does the error code read and did you select any capabilities in the package.Appxmanifest?

Comment: I am able connect to the camera. Actually the DeviceUri should be properly formatted. For Reolink 410 the device uri should be like this: 
`rtsp://admin:Password@192.168.1.141:554//h264Preview_01_main` I am able to take pictures but still not able to make videos.

Comment: initial your question was about getting a preview, right?

Comment: So what is the exception message when you trying to record a video?

Comment: {"The specified object or value does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36D5)"}

Comment: Based on your code, you are using `MediaEncodingProfile.CreateHevc`, right? Have you tried the official [CameraAdvancedCapture sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraAdvancedCapture) with the uri camera?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Actually, CameraAdvancedCapture sample is not for recording video but I have tried [CameraVideoStabilization](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraVideoStabilization) Sample. I have interesting find that if I have another local USB camera connected then recording video with remote Uri camera works, but if only remote Uri camera is connected, I can only take pictures but video recording doesn't work and I get the previously mentioned exception. So it seems to be a bug in UWP APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to set the MediaCaptureInitializationSettings like this:

```
 MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mcis = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
 {   
     DeviceUri = new Uri("rtsp://login:password@192.168.178.30/axis-media/media.amp", 
     UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
 };
 await mc.InitializeAsync(mcis);
```

Start end stop recording is for the IP camera just like any other USB camera:

```
if(_isRecording)
{
    await CE.Source.StopRecordAsync();
    _isRecording = false;
}
else
{
    StorageFile file = await (KnownFolders.CameraRoll).CreateFileAsync("Axis.mp4",
    CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    
    var encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
    await CE.Source.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, file);
    _isRecording = true;
}
```

In the package manifest I have check: Microphone, Pictureslibrary,VideoLibrary, WebCam and internet(server&client)

your specific camera the 410 (not 410W) should use rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.141/h264Preview_01_sub (source: https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Reolink)

Comment: The problem with video is that following instruction throws exception:
await CE.Source.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, file);
{"The specified object or value does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36D5)"}

Comment: In your string there is a '//' after the portnumber 554. Make sure that is a single '/'  . rtsp://admin:Password@192.168.1.141:554//h264Preview_01_main' ==>rtsp://admin:Password@192.168.1.141:554/h264Preview_01_main' or rtsp://admin:Password@192.168.1.141:554/h264Preview_01_sub

Personaly I would leave the portnumber out too. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Please note that I have successfully connected to camera, taken pictures and preview from it. I only have problem with video recording.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet where it throws the exception?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I have edited my post and provided the code which I am using.

Comment: I have tested your lowlag recording code on my axis camera and it worked without a problem.the conclusion needs to be that your problems are not in the code. Suspects for your problem are now down to the connectionstring for the video stream, the codec, write access for the file and/or the Package.appxmanifest settings ,imo. 
Btw: Did you test any other IP camera? Or did you test this camera with other software on the same system?